# set options for replicating slow queries in SSMS

Tags: query-performance, execution-plan

I am investigating a slow ad-hoc query(about 45 seconds) from our application.  I am not able to replicate the slowness in ssms however to investigate indexing, reads, etc.  I've attempted to use the same set options that the query from the app uses, but it still runs in less than a second in SSMS.  Questions about what I should do are below:

1. I have reviewed [Slow in the App, fast in SSMS](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html), and pulled the set options by using sp_whoisactive.  This is the only way I know to get those options?  Are there ways to get them via trace, extended events, etc.?  below is the info.  I added the ones in the box to SSMS when I ran the query in order to replicate the slowness.  Would I need to add others that might be different in SSMS then the app in order to replicate this slowness?
   [image: set options]

2.) I pulled the exec plan from the @get_plans options of sp_whoisactive, however, those won't show run time stats like reads.  Is there a way to get the run time stats another way?  the plan in SSMS is different then the sp_whoisactive one.